# Entity Framework 5 reload from database using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this line of code which loads some data from my database using a stored procedure.

```
List<myObj) myObjs = context.myStoredProc(myParameter).ToList();
```

I can't find the right syntax to force a reload from the database and replace the current data with data from the database.

I am trying:

```
context.Entry().Reload();
```

but this is wrong because I do not know what goes in the brackets.

I have other entities on this context which are tracked. The context is not disposed.

```
List<myObj) myObjs = context.myStoredProc(myParameter).ToList();
```

Does not overwrite the current values.

Comment: Sorry something wrong - the rest of the question is being cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the results of `context.myStoredProc(myParameter).ToList();` is a list of tracked entities, you will need to call `myObjs = context.myStoredProc(myParameter).ToList();` again.

Comment: I have other entities on this context which are tracked.The context is not disposed and List<myObj) myObjs = context.myStoredProc(myParameter).ToList(); does not refresh from database